# echo query return data from array

Tags: php, mysql

This is the php code that I wrote to retrieve data from my database, When i am trying to echo the required data nothing is displayed, if I `json_encode` result and echo it, then I can see that there is data in side the array.

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    $retval = $connect->query("SELECT user_name FROM users");
    $result = array();
    while ($record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $record;
        echo $result['user_name'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: and what about `echo $record['user_name']` ??

Comment: what is the purpose to `echo` inside `while`? if necessary then `echo $record['user_name'];`

Comment: Yes change the variable name as $record not $result.

Comment: @devpro Yes it worked but shouldn't I bee echoing $result since im storing the record item in result

Comment: `$result[] = $record;` this will not work as u want inside the array but this will work `$result = $record;` because u r storing the data in an array `$result`

Comment: @devpro  wrong . print_r($result); will work inside while,since it's array. his purpose of `$result[] = ...` is to store all data

Comment: *if I json_encode result and echo it, then I can see that there is data in side the array.* yes it will give u result in array

Comment: @Anant: yes i know, but as OP is using, it will not work, because its an array.

Comment: @devrop yea thanks it worked, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: posted with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, if you want to print `user_name` inside the `while` loop than no need to store in another array.

You can just use like:

```
<?php
while ($record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo $record['user_name']; // will print all user_name
}
?>
```

If you want to use `$result` somewhere else, as you are talking about the `json_encode()` than you can store it in `$result` array.

```
<?php
while ($record = $retval->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo $record['user_name']; // will print all user_name
  $result[] = $record;    // will store all username in result array
}
?>
```

**From your question:** *if I json_encode result and echo it, then I can see that there is data in side the array.* Yes [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will work because you are using array.